# How can I use object props in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

The vue.js documentation has this as an example:

```
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
  return { counter: this.initialCounter }
}
```

However, `initialCounter` works in my template, but `counter` does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the full code:

```
<update-counter initialCounter="1" inline-template>
    <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">My Counter @{{ initialCounter }}</div>
```

Edit: I narrowed down my issue. If I pass a variable like this it works:

```
<update-partner :initial-counter="1" inline-template>
```

But if I pass an object, it doesn't work:

```
<update-partner :initial-counter="users" inline-template>
```

When I pass that object, `initialCounter` works in my template, but `counter` does not.

When I pass an integer, both variables work.

What do I need to do differently when I pass an object?

Comment: Can you put more code to make it clear, is `initialCounter` being populated asynchronously in parent component?

Comment: @saurabh Thanks I added more information.

Comment: Where is your users defined, how do they look like?

Comment: The users var is set by the parent component on mount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is occurring as when you are doing following in the component:

```
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
  return { counter: this.initialCounter }
}
```

You are assigning `counter` initial value of `initialCounter`, which you change later in `mounted` block. If you need to change value to set in `counter`, you have to set a watcher on `initialCounter`, like following:

```
  watch:{
    initialCounter: function(newVal){
      this.counter = newVal;
    }
  }
```

You can see working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/s4yzrvoy/).